# Need help understanding this macro from ltp testsuite file tst_res.c

Tags: c, macros

What does this macro do? I am not able to understand its definition:

```
#define PAIR(def) [def] = { .name = #def, .val = def, },
```

From : ltp-full-20120401/lib/tst_res.c line 183

You can get the source from this [link](http://sourceforge.net/projects/ltp/files/LTP%20Source/ltp-20120401/ltp-full-20120401.bz2/download)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like it is used to initialize an array of structs.

```
#define PAIR(def) [def] = { .name = #def, .val = def, },
```

the macro used as follows `PAIR(FOOBAR)` would expand to:

```
[FOOBAR] = { .name = "FOOBAR", .val = FOOBAR, },
```

`.name` and `.val` would be members of the `struct` type of the array elements.

Comment: Thanks! I see. Can you suggest a reference to learn complicated C macros ?

Comment: @abc - A good advice is *not* to use complicated C macros. :-) When people have to ask what it does, it is not good code.

Comment: unexperienced C programmers may ask what a piece of code does; does it mean it is not good code? I mean, judging the goodness or badness of code/macro through questions people may ask won't produce "acceptable judgements"; this macro is simple (for whoever is accustomed to macro) and a simple "commodity". OT philosophy